# How to remove lines inside a table from a Migradoc pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a pdf that was made using Migradoc, which i have a table and in this table it's appearing some lines surrounding the rows and columns that look like borders. These lines just appear when i open the pdf in the browser, but when i print it or open in pdf reader it doesn't happen.
I've already tried to remove all the borders from the table, also i tried to add borders with the same background color of the rows, but the lines persist.

The result that i expect is to remove those lines.

[image: imagem da tabela]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use semi-transparent colours to fill the cell backgrounds. The PDF viewer probably draws those cells with a small overlap, thus creating the visible "borders".

Solution: Use colours with 100% opacity as background colour and the lines should no longer be visible.

Comment: How can I do it ?
It's a Row class.